# How can I evaluate the congruency of an AKS primality test?

Tags: prime-numbers

Despite the fact primality test is a mathematical issue, it plays a part on the security of many cryptosystems such as RSA. I was trying to understand how it works until I came to the following congruency:

```
〖(X+a)〗^p≡X^p+a (mod X^r-1,p)
```

The above reduces evaluating the initial congruency `〖(X+a)〗^p≡X^p+a (mod p)` to have less coefficient. How do we evaluate the above one?

Answer (score 1):

This is never "evaluated" as such. The above equation must **hold** for the number to be prime for certain $a$, or else it's composite.

See [the algorithm on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test#Algorithm) to exactly see for which $a$ the equation is tested.